# How to fit white background behind fa-3x (Font-awesome) icons

Tags: css

I find it difficult to customize the background behind the font-awesome icons I have created. I'm trying to make a white background which does to extends the actually icon.

Right now it looks like the image bolow:

[image]

Here you can see that the white background is taken too much space around the icon.

**Code**

```
 <div class="footer-icons">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x pen-btn"></i></a>
                </div>
```

**Css**

```
 .footer-icons a {
    padding-right: 10px; 
    color: green; 
 }

 .footer-icons i {
    background-color: white;   
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
 }
```

Have tried with padding-left and right with a negative value to make it smaller (stay inside the green icon)

If i remove the padding, it looks like this:

[image]

Hope someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a font, adjust it with `line-height`. I would suggest using an image (e.g., png, svg, gif). Here's a fiddle example for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/4ht7fq91/

Comment: That almost helped... but you can still see it touches the left side when you add a hover color to it. Any way to only move the white background a little to the right?

Comment: @Mikkel It's not perfect. Unfortunately that's how the font is. It's why I suggested using an image.

Comment: So using an image for the icons.. or an image for the white background?

Comment: Use an image for the icons.